# Error subquery on materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to create a materialized view but  when I run it, it shows me an error because of the subqueries. I saw in oracle doc that subqueries are allow to use them in materialized view into the FROM and WHERE sentences. I put here the subquery so you may help me to solve the problem.

```
    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
    ("id", "status", "id_service") 
    INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber_events" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
    ("created_at", "id_event", "billed", "percent_billed", "id_service")
    INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber_status" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
    ("id_status")
    INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "service" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
    ("id", "price", "revenue")
    INCLUDING NEW VALUES;


    CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "bill_arpu_month_by_service"
    TABLESPACE plat_dat
    BUILD IMMEDIATE
    REFRESH FORCE 
    START WITH sysdate NEXT +1 MONTH 
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    AS

    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT created, service, billed, global_user_actives, optin, optout, new_users, dif, 
    global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) as actives_S_M, 
    global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users as actives_E_M, 
    round((CASE WHEN (global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users) =0 THEN 0 
    ELSE (billed/(global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users)) * service_mult END),2) arpu

    FROM 
    ( select to_char("created_at", 'yyyymm') "CREATED", AVG("service"."id") service,
    SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1', '5', '3') and "billed" = '1' THEN 1 WHEN "id_event" IN ('6', '4') and "billed" = '1' THEN "percent_billed"/100 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLED, 
    (select count("id") from "subscriber" join "subscriber_status" on "subscriber"."status" = "subscriber_status"."id_status" where "subscriber"."status" = 1 and "subscriber"."id_service" = "service"."id") as global_user_actives, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS optin, SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS optout, (SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1','3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as new_users, 
    ((select count("id") from "subscriber" join "subscriber_status" on "subscriber"."status" = "subscriber_status"."id_status" where "subscriber"."status" = 1 and "subscriber"."id_service" = "service"."id") - (SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1','3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))) as dif, 

    (COALESCE( AVG("service"."price")*AVG("service"."revenue")/100 , 0)) as service_mult

    from "subscriber_events" 
    JOIN "service" ON "subscriber_events"."id_service" = "service"."id" 
    where "id_event" IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') 
    group by "service"."id", to_char("created_at", 'yyyymm') order by "service"."id", "CREATED" DESC ) 
    ORDER BY "SERVICE", "CREATED" DESC);


> Error SQL: ORA-22818: expresiones de subconsulta no permitidas aquí
> 22818. 00000 - "subquery expressions not allowed here"  
> *Cause: An attempt was made to use a subquery expression where these are not supported.  
> *Action: Rewrite the statement without the subquery expression.
```

Comment: please fomat it properly use `{}` on top to edit

Answer (score 2):

Materialized views do no support subqueries - full stop. Another thing to note, I believe that Oracle does not support the ANSI join syntax i.e. JOIN, INNER JOIN etc. and prefers the original "," separated syntax i.e.

```
/*This syntax is not supported*/
SELECT * 
      FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2
        ON TABLE1.col1 = TABLE2.col2


/*This syntax is preferred*/
SELECT *  FROM 
        TABLE1,
        TABLE2
         WHERE TABLE1.col1 = TABLE2.col2
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#i1007028) for all restrictions on fast refresh materialized views

Comment: Oracle **does** support current ANSI syntax on joins, outer, inner etc., and has for a very long time.

Comment: I realise that they do support ANSI. However, I meant in the context of my comment i.e. Fast Refresh Materialized View. My understanding was that (at least in 10gR2) ansi join syntax was not supported for fast refresh. I'm completely open to being corrected on this.

Answer (score 2):

What I finally did was to create a view without joins and then create the materialized view based on that view and It worked .. I show you what I did in case something is wront on it.
Thanks!

#### LOGS:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
("id", "status", "id_service") 
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber_events" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
("created_at", "id_event", "billed", "percent_billed", "id_service")
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "subscriber_status" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
("id_status")
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "service" WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID
("id", "price", "revenue")
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

#### VIEW:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "bill_arpu_month_view" as
select to_char("created_at", 'yyyymm') "CREATED", AVG("service"."id") service,
SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1', '5', '3') and "billed" = '1' THEN 1 WHEN "id_event" IN ('6', '4') and "billed" = '1' THEN "percent_billed"/100 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLED, 
(select count("id") from "subscriber" join "subscriber_status" on "subscriber"."status" = "subscriber_status"."id_status" where "subscriber"."status" = 1 and "subscriber"."id_service" = "service"."id") as global_user_actives, 
SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS optin, SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS optout, (SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1','3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as new_users, 
((select count("id") from "subscriber", "subscriber_status" where "subscriber"."status" = "subscriber_status"."id_status" and "subscriber"."status" = 1 and "subscriber"."id_service" = "service"."id") - (SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('1','3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM( CASE WHEN "id_event" IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))) as dif, 

(COALESCE( AVG("service"."price")*AVG("service"."revenue")/100 , 0)) as service_mult

from "subscriber_events", "service" 
    WHERE "subscriber_events"."id_service" = "service"."id" 
AND "id_event" IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6') 
group by "service"."id", to_char("created_at", 'yyyymm') order by "service"."id", "CREATED" DESC ;
```

#### MATERIALIZED VIEW:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "bill_arpu_month_by_service"
TABLESPACE plat_dat
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE 
AS
SELECT created, service, billed, global_user_actives, optin, optout, new_users, dif, 
global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) as actives_S_M, 
global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users as actives_E_M, 
round((CASE WHEN (global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users) =0 THEN 0 
      ELSE (billed/(global_user_actives - SUM(new_users) OVER (PARTITION BY service ORDER BY created DESC) + new_users)) * service_mult END),2) arpu
FROM 
"bill_arpu_month_view"
ORDER BY "SERVICE", "CREATED" DESC;
```